# sed to find first occurrence of a pattern AFTER finding another pattern

Tags: sed

Is there a way to prepend something to the first occurrence of a line of code ONLY after the occurrence of another pattern? I want to turn off the addTween line (by prepending a double slash comment) ONLY for "Group2", which is demarcated by an auto-generated comment "// Group2". 
In other words, I want to

1. search for the occurrence of "// Group2"
2. use sed to prepend a comment for the addTween line only for Group2 only.

**Input file:**

```
// Group1
this.shape = new cjs.Shape();
this.shape.graphics.f().s("#663300").ss(1,1,1).p("EBHXAAAQAAW105QIQ06QJ9kAAQ9jAA05wJQ06wIAA21QAA2zU6wJQU5wIdjAAQdkAAU6QIQU5QJAAWzg");
this.shape.setTransform(1005.55,596.9);

this.shape_1 = new cjs.Shape();
this.shape_1.graphics.f("#E5CCFF").s().p("EgydAm9Q05wJAA20QAA2zU5wJQU6wIdjgBQdkABU5QIQU6QJAAWzQAAW006QJQ05QJ9kgBQ9jAB06wJg");
this.shape_1.setTransform(1005.55,596.9);

this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get({}).to({state:[{t:this.shape_1},{t:this.shape}]}).wait(1));

// Group2
this.shape_2 = new cjs.Shape();
this.shape_2.graphics.f().s("#666600").ss(44.3,1,1).p("EhDmgf6MCHNAAAMAAAA/1MiHNAAAg");
this.shape_2.setTransform(833.25,400.65);

this.shape_3 = new cjs.Shape();
this.shape_3.graphics.f("#336699").s().p("EhDmAf7MAAAg/1MCHNAAAMAAAA/1g");
this.shape_3.setTransform(833.25,400.65);

this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get({}).to({state:[{t:this.shape_3},{t:this.shape_2}]}).wait(1));
```

**Output file: (note only change is last line got a comment double  slash prepended to it)**

```
// Group1

this.shape = new cjs.Shape();
this.shape.graphics.f().s("#663300").ss(1,1,1).p("EBHXAAAQAAW105QIQ06QJ9kAAQ9jAA05wJQ06wIAA21QAA2zU6wJQU5wIdjAAQdkAAU6QIQU5QJAAWzg");
this.shape.setTransform(1005.55,596.9);

this.shape_1 = new cjs.Shape();
this.shape_1.graphics.f("#E5CCFF").s().p("EgydAm9Q05wJAA20QAA2zU5wJQU6wIdjgBQdkABU5QIQU6QJAAWzQAAW006QJQ05QJ9kgBQ9jAB06wJg");
this.shape_1.setTransform(1005.55,596.9);

this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get({}).to({state:[{t:this.shape_1},{t:this.shape}]}).wait(1));

// Group2

this.shape_2 = new cjs.Shape();
this.shape_2.graphics.f().s("#666600").ss(44.3,1,1).p("EhDmgf6MCHNAAAMAAAA/1MiHNAAAg");
this.shape_2.setTransform(833.25,400.65);

this.shape_3 = new cjs.Shape();
this.shape_3.graphics.f("#336699").s().p("EhDmAf7MAAAg/1MCHNAAAMAAAA/1g");
this.shape_3.setTransform(833.25,400.65);

//this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get({}).to({state:[{t:this.shape_3},{t:this.shape_2}]}).wait(1));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed '/\/\/ Group2/,/addTween/ s/^.*addTween/\/\/&/' file
```

This searches for the text between `// Group2` and the following `addTween` and adds `//` to the line containing `addTween`.

Comment: Freddy, thank you VERY MUCH! You are truly great.

Comment: Actually, do you know a way to also undo this process? I realized I will have to comment out all the tweens and then selectively bring back some.

Comment: Reverse operation: `sed '/\/\/ Group2/,/\/\/.*addTween/ s/^\/\/\(.*addTween\)/\1/' file`

Comment: wow, thank you very much!!